# this blade page keeps reloading after form submission even when im using post method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-10

i am trying to create a function that facilitates the generation of a timetable for examination. I have the courses and lecturers tables working fine but the function for generating timetable seems not to work.The system ought to generate a timetable in a pdf format that is to be printed or download. i tried using dd() to debug but nothing works.

this is the content of the blade file

```
@extends('layouts.guest')
@include('user.sidebar')
<main class="main-content position-relative max-height-vh-100 h-100 mt-1 border-radius-lg">
    @include('user.topmenu')
    @if(Session::has('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{ Session::get('success') }}
    </div>
    @endif
    @yield('content')

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">Generate Timetable</div>

                    <div class="card-body">
                        <form action="{{ route('generate.timetable') }}" method="POST">
                            @csrf
                            @method('POST')
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="start">Select Exams Start Date:</label>
                                <input type="date" name="start" class="form-control @error('start') is-invalid @enderror">
                                @error('start')
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback">{{ $message }}</div>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="end">Select Exams End Date:</label>
                                <input type="date" name="end"
                             
                            class="form-control @error('end') is-invalid @enderror">
                                @error('end')
                                    <div
                             
                            class="invalid-feedback">{{ $message }}</div>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                            <div
 
class="form-group">
    <label for="venues">Exam Venues (separated by comma):</label>
    <input type="text"  name="venues" class="form-control @error('venues.*') is-invalid @enderror" data-role="tagsinput">
    @error('venues.*')
        <div class="invalid-feedback">{{ $message }}</div>
    @enderror
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="timestart">Select Exams Start Time:</label>
    <input type="time" name="timestart"  class="form-control @error('timestart') is-invalid @enderror" >
    @error('timestart')
        <div class="invalid-feedback">{{ $message }}</div>
    @enderror 
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="timeend">Select Exams End Time:</label>
    <input type="time" name="timeend" class="form-control @error('timeend') is-invalid @enderror">
    @error('timeend')
        <div class="invalid-feedback">{{ $message }}</div>
    @enderror
</div>
                        
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Generate Timetable</button>
                        </form>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

and now this is the controller that processes it

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Course;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Faculty;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
use PDF;

class FacultyController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('user.timetable');
    }

    public function generateTimetable(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'start' => 'required|date',
            'end' => 'required|date|after:start',
            'venues' => 'required|array',
            'venues.*' => 'required|string',
            'timestart' => 'required|date_format:H:i',
            'timeend' => 'required|date_format:H:i|after:timestart',
        ]);

        // Get the selected deadline for exams
        $startDate = $request->input('start');
        $endDate = $request->input('end');
        $venues = $request->input('venues');
        $deadline = $endDate; // Use the end date as the deadline

        // Get the authenticated user
        $user = auth()->user();

        // Fetch all courses related to the authenticated user
        $courses = Course::where('user_id', $user->id)->get();

        // Generate timetable data
        $timetable = [];

        foreach ($courses as $course) {
            // Fetch the two attached lecturers for the course
            $lecturers = $course->lecturers()->take(2)->get();

            // Fetch a random third lecturer from other users
            $thirdLecturer = User::whereNotNull('lecturers')
                ->whereNotIn('id', $lecturers->pluck('id'))
                ->inRandomOrder()
                ->first();

            // Attach the third lecturer to the course
            $lecturers[] = $thirdLecturer;

            // Generate exam date within the selected deadline
            $examDate = $this->generateExamDate($startDate, $endDate);

            // Generate exam time between the selected start and end time
            $examTime = $this->generateExamTime($request->input('timestart'), $request->input('timeend'));

            // Generate a venue for the exam
            $venue = $request->input('venues')[array_rand($venues)];

            // Create a timetable entry for the course
            $timetableItem = [
                'time' => $examTime,
                'course_name' => $course->name,
                'course_code' => $course->code,
                'invigilators' => $lecturers->pluck('name')->implode(', '),
                'venue' => $venue,
                'date' => $examDate,
            ];

            $timetable[] = $timetableItem;
        }

        // Store timetable data in session
        Session::put('timetable', $timetable);

        // Redirect to timetable-preview page
        return redirect()->route('timetable-preview');
    }

    public function timetablePreview()
    {
        // Retrieve timetable data from the session
        $timetable = session('timetable');

        return view('user.timetable-preview', compact('timetable'));
    }

    private function generateExamDate($startDate, $endDate)
    {
        $startTimestamp = strtotime($startDate);
        $endTimestamp = strtotime($endDate);

        // Calculate the number of days between the start and end date
        $days = ($endTimestamp - $startTimestamp) / (60 * 60 * 24);

        // Generate a random date within the selected start and end date
        $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+$days days", $startTimestamp));

        // Ensure the generated date falls on a weekday (Monday to Friday)
        while (date('N', strtotime($date)) >= 6) {
            $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date)));
        }

        return $date;
    }

    private function generateExamTime($startTime, $endTime)
    {
        // Generate a random time between the given start and end time
        $startTimestamp = strtotime($startTime);
        $endTimestamp = strtotime($endTime);

        $timestamp = rand($startTimestamp, $endTimestamp);
        $time = date('H:i', $timestamp);

        return $time;
    }
}
```

this is the route

```
Route::post('generatetimetable', [FacultyController::class, 'generateTimetable'])->name('generate.timetable');

Route::get('/timetable-preview', [FacultyController::class, 'timetablePreview'])->name('timetable-preview');
```

Comment: Since you `@extends('layouts.guest')`, wouldn't you need a `@section('content')` or something that gets `@yield`ed in your layout?

Comment: its in the file, sorry i didnt add that in the question

Comment: are you sure that it is submitted ? what if it is redirect back because the validation failed.

Comment: fyi, the `for` attribute on labels should point to an `id` attribute. None of your inputs has an `id`

Comment: im using the name attribute to connect to the function

Comment: It has nothing to do with connecting to a function and it was only an fyi, so no so relevant. More info: [HTML attribute: for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/for)

Comment: okay thanks...noted

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the page from reloading, at the end of your function you must return your file and not the route name `return redirect()->route('timetable-preview');`

```
To prevent the page from reloading, at the end of your function you must return your file and not the route name `return redirect()->route('timetable-preview');`

 public function generateTimetable(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'start' => 'required|date',
        'end' => 'required|date|after:start',
        'venues' => 'required|array',
        'venues.*' => 'required|string',
        'timestart' => 'required|date_format:H:i',
        'timeend' => 'required|date_format:H:i|after:timestart',
    ]);

    // Get the selected deadline for exams
    $startDate = $request->input('start');
    $endDate = $request->input('end');
    $venues = $request->input('venues');
    $deadline = $endDate; // Use the end date as the deadline

    // Get the authenticated user
    $user = auth()->user();

    // Fetch all courses related to the authenticated user
    $courses = Course::where('user_id', $user->id)->get();

    // Generate timetable data
    $timetable = [];

    foreach ($courses as $course) {
        // Fetch the two attached lecturers for the course
        $lecturers = $course->lecturers()->take(2)->get();

        // Fetch a random third lecturer from other users
        $thirdLecturer = User::whereNotNull('lecturers')
            ->whereNotIn('id', $lecturers->pluck('id'))
            ->inRandomOrder()
            ->first();

        // Attach the third lecturer to the course
        $lecturers[] = $thirdLecturer;

        // Generate exam date within the selected deadline
        $examDate = $this->generateExamDate($startDate, $endDate);

        // Generate exam time between the selected start and end time
        $examTime = $this->generateExamTime($request->input('timestart'), $request->input('timeend'));

        // Generate a venue for the exam
        $venue = $request->input('venues')[array_rand($venues)];

        // Create a timetable entry for the course
        $timetableItem = [
            'time' => $examTime,
            'course_name' => $course->name,
            'course_code' => $course->code,
            'invigilators' => $lecturers->pluck('name')->implode(', '),
            'venue' => $venue,
            'date' => $examDate,
        ];

        $timetable[] = $timetableItem;
    }

    // Store timetable data in session
    Session::put('timetable', $timetable);

    // Redirect to timetable-preview page
    //return redirect()->route('timetable-preview');

    //make pdf file
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('user.timetable-preview',
                ['timetable' => $timetable])->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');

        $filename = __('file.name') . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . '.pdf';

        return $pdf->stream($filename);

}
```

Comment: okay how do i do that?

Comment: i edited answer to suggest a code

Comment: okay did that, still not working